# correct shape (BS,H,W,C) not working in torchvision.utils.save_image

Tags: python, pytorch, computer-vision, torchvision

Let's BS be the batch size, H the height, w the weight, and c the number of channels which is 3 in my case.

When I save my image in this shape (BS,C,H,W) with

```
torchvision.utils.save_image(image, path)
```

it works very well but the image is unreadable since the format is wrong.

But when I am reshaping my image into the right format which is (BS,H,W,C), The code below does not work

```
image = image.reshape(BS,H,W,C)  
torchvision.utils.save_image(image, path)
```

Here is the error that I am stuck in:

> TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 256), |u1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wanted your image to have size `(BS, C, H, W)`, but you are incorrectly reshaping it.

Assuming the `image.shape` is `(BS, H, W, C)`, perhaps you meant to perform `image = image.permute(0, 3, 1, 2)` which moves the channel dimension in the second position, to obtain the required shape.